# Using an if statement for terminating (return) the function for null conditionals, when is it best to introduce a variable?

Tags: python

I have an excel file with multiple tags in the format of key-value pairs. I want to perform some tasks using the value of each tag only when a key has a value. When is it best to introduce a variable for storing the value? In advance or right after the check of the value that actually exists, and won't exit the function immediately, thus there is a meaning to reserve space for that? Note, that this function will run hundreds of times scanning multiple tags in that file.

```
def getValue(file):
   if (file.myValue == ""):
      return "Empty string"
   myVal = file.myValue
   # now do stuff using the variable `myVal` that I have just declared/initialised
   # ...
```

**OR**

```
def getValue(file):
   myVal = file.myValue
   if (myVal == ""):
      return "Empty string"

   # do stuff using the variable `myVal` I have already declared/initialized in advance
   # ...
```

Comment: Short-circuiting/returning early is preferred as it reduces nesting. So no "else" (looking at your comment in second case). I prefer first one as we might have a lot of such variables and it just obscures readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python >= 3.8, you can use a named assignment to avoid that pattern:

```
def getValue(file):
    if (myVal := file.myValue) == "":
        return "Empty string"
    # do stuff with myVal
```

Otherwise I'd do the assignment first:

```
def getValue(file):
    myVal = file.myValue
    if myVal == "":
        return "Empty string"
```

It may not make a difference in terms of performance (minute, if anything), but it reduces code length with no cost to readability.

Comment: `myVal` is _not_ out of scope after the `if`? I am shocked.

Comment: @phipsgabler No, that's the whole point. Also, `if` blocks or loop bodies never open new scope in Python. And, of course, the assignment `myVal := file.myValue` has to be executed for the condition to be evaluated.

Comment: I know about the latter, so I should have expected it, but I disagree about it being "the whole point". Isn't that exactly to avoid having to declare a variable outside the block it is used in -- for readability? Otherwise, what would be the advantage over the OP's alternative 2?

Comment: (I don't want to start a discussion, though, lets just leave it :))

Comment: I'd recommend you read PEP which introduced the so-called walrus operator, formally named assignment expression - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/ @phipsgabler :) It shows a lot of justification and examples of usage. I personally like it for regex stuff because you have to check for non-null match anyway to proceed

Comment: I would also stand by the assignment expression, and fallback to assigning before the conditional, if anything seems weird. Also, remember to use `if not myVal` to evaluate empty objects such as lists, strings and alike. Then, you'd have `if not (myVal := file.myValue)`, which is also more readable (in my humble opinion)

Comment: @h4z3 I have read that, multiple times in fact, and like to use the walrus myself. Yet, none of the [examples posed there](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#examples) uses the assigned variable after the block in which it occurs (counting `else` as part of `if`). Yes, I do understand why it still behaves this way -- it just makes my mental evaluator lag a bit. Not a critique of the design, but more of usage style.

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I am going with @user2390182 with the `if (myVal := file.myValue)` syntax since doesn't have additional operational cost and is more readable as well as reduces the length of the code.

Comment: @joshmeranda please don't make such edits. Nowhere did the OP state that they wanted to do truth value testing. On the contrary, the output suggests a very specific test for the empty string,  not for 0 or an empty list.